# Display custom taxonomy in a list using the_term_list() in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need help with displaying my custom taxonomies in a ul using the_term_list().

I can get it to list all the terms I want, but I need them in an unordered list, rather than just a list of links separated by comments.

Here's what I've got to work with:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'skills', '<h5>Project Role</h5> ', ', ', '', ); ?>
```

Here's the WordPress function reference, if you need it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list

Answer (score 2):

This should get your custom taxonomies displaying in an unordered list with your h5 title up top:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'skills', '<h5>Project Role</h5><ul><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//    Use this code
    <?php
    $taxonomy     = 'product-category';
    $orderby      = 'name';
    $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
    $title        = '';
    $empty        = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'=> $taxonomy, 'orderby' => $orderby,  'show_count' => $show_count, 'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts, 'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
        'title_li'     => $title, 'hide_empty'   => $empty ); ?>
        <ul class="sidebar_cat" data-role="listview"> <?php $variable = wp_list_categories( $args ); $variable = str_replace(array('(',')'), '', $variable);    $variable = str_replace('(', '<span class="ui-li-count">', $variable);
        $variable = str_replace(')', '</span>', $variable);   echo $variable; ?>
        </ul>
```